# How many are the sequences of the type $abc$ such that...

Tags: combinatorics

How many are the sequences of the type $abc$ such that

(i) a is an integer between 1 and 9, b and c are integers between 0 and 9, and it is $a> b> c$;

(ii) a is an integer between 1 and 9, b and c are integers between 0 and 9, and is $a ≥ b ≥ c$.

My guess is that the first one is $9!9!8!$ and the second one is $9!9!9!$.

Comment: Why do you think it's $9!9!8!$?

Comment: Both are very incorrect.  You are throwing around factorials like its candy at a parade... stop and think about what a factorial does and is used for.  Note, $9!9!8!$ is some sixteen digits long, but it should be obvious that there are at most $1000$ sequences since each sequence can be interpreted as a three-digit number.

Comment: @kingW3 because I assumed the case in which a is 9 so that you have 9 choices of b and if b is 8 you have 8 choices for c. I know it's wrong.

Comment: Ignoring the correctness of your argument, if you truly had 9 choices for $a$ and 9 choices for $b$, etc... then that would lead to $9\times 9\times 8$ total possibilities, not $9!\times 9!\times 8!$.  That being said, multiplication principle (rule of product) only works in the situation where number of options available *does not depend on earlier choices*, but as you should have noticed, while $a$ originally has nine options, depending on which option was selected $b$ will have a different number of options available (e.g. if $a$ was selected to be $5$, $b$ has only 4 options, not 8*).

Comment: One more nitpick., although the class you were asked this question in may eventually touch on probability or statistics, this question itself does not have anything to do with either topic and so deserves the more general tag of 'combinatorics.'  Many questions in combinatorics lead to interesting questions in probability if reworded in the right way, however many more questions in combinatorics don't have anything to do with probability and this is one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

How many 3-element subsets are there of $\{0,1,2,3,\dots,9\}$?

What does this have to do with your problem?  Is there any nice way to transform a sequence with the properties you are looking at into a 3-element subset and vice versa?  If you try to do this for the second part of the problem, what types of sequences did you miss counting that you should have counted?  How can you count what was missed?